# To draw circles intersecting with lines using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to draw the following figure using tikz?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 4):

Since this seems to be your first post, here is a start.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={rr=2;alpha=30;},>=latex,angle eccentricity=1.5]
 \draw[dashed] (-3*rr,0) coordinate (l) -- (3*rr,0) coordinate (r);
 \draw (-rr,0) coordinate (c1) circle[radius=rr] 
    (rr,0) coordinate (c2) circle[radius=rr];
 \draw[thick,->] (c1) ++ (180-alpha:1.5*rr)
  coordinate[label=above:$\SI{20}{\meter/\second}$,label=below left:$u_1$] (u1) 
  edge[->] ++ (-alpha:0.5*rr)
  -- (c1) -- ++ (-alpha-90:1.5*rr) 
  coordinate[label=left:$v_1$] (v1)
  pic[-,angle radius=7mm,draw,"\pgfmathparse{alpha}\SI{\pgfmathresult}{\degree}"]{angle={u1--c1--l}}
  pic[-,angle radius=6mm,draw,"$\phi_1$"]{angle={l--c1--v1}};
 \draw[thick,->] (c2) ++ (90-alpha:1.5*rr)
  coordinate[label=above:$\SI{30}{\meter/\second}$,label=below right:$u_2$] (u2) 
  edge[->] ++ (-90-alpha:0.5*rr)
  -- (c2) -- ++ (-alpha:1.5*rr) 
  coordinate[label=above:$v_2$] (v2)
  pic[-,angle radius=7mm,draw,"\pgfmathparse{int(90-alpha)}\SI{\pgfmathresult}{\degree}"]{angle={r--c2--u2}}
  pic[-,angle radius=8mm,draw,"$\phi_2$"]{angle={v2--c2--r}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I did not have the patience to punch in all the texts. This is the problem with such questions: you ask others to punch in texts from a screen shot. Therefore, I'd kindly like to ask you to provide a minimal example next time, from which others can just copy the texts.

Comment: `edge` does not need `[->]` I think.